# embed jar file in html page

Tags: html, applet

I have a jar file and want to embed it into the html page, I have tried the following code:

```
 <APPLET ARCHIVE="myapplet.jar" CODE="myapplet.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200>
 </APPLET>
```

is it possible if I only want to embed jar file instead of any class files because I have many class files and I am not sure do I need to embed all of them, i am new in this field, anyone could help me with it? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can anyone help me with this question please, I really apprecaite any kind help!

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible if I only want to embed jar file instead of any class files

Sure it is possible.  But then, at least one Jar will need to *contain* at least one class (the applet class itself).  The `code` attribute must **identify** the applet class (which might be in a Jar or loose on the server).

Basically I find your question confusing.